# Display Successful Message after HttpPost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which has a registration form. If the registration form is submitted I want to return to the same view and display a temporary `Bootstrap Well` and then fade it out. Check my idea out in my controller

**Controller**

```
// Insert User
[HttpPost]
public void AddUser(ResourceViewModel resourceInfo)
{
    // Fetch data from ViewModel as parameters Execute Stored Procedure

    db_RIRO.sp_InsertNewUser(resourceInfo.Username, resourceInfo.Password);
    db_RIRO.SaveChanges()

    // My Idea
    if (storedProcedure succesful)
    { // display success ViewBag in view }
    else 
    {
      // display failed ViewBag in view
    }

}
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label lb-sm" for="textinput">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Password, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label lb-sm" for="textinput">Username</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Username, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })

    </div>
</div>
```

How would I achieve this using `ViewBag`?

Comment: Assign your message to `TempData`, redirect, and in the method you redirect to, read it from `TempData`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said whether you return to the same view or not, but in whatever view you *do* return to, you can print the TempData out.

Here's a basic example:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddUser(ResourceViewModel resourceInfo)
{
    // Fetch data from ViewModel as parameters Execute Stored Procedure

    db_RIRO.sp_InsertNewUser(resourceInfo.Username, resourceInfo.Password);
    db_RIRO.SaveChanges()

    // My Idea
    if (storedProcedure succesful)
    { 
      // display success tempdata in view 
      TempData["Message"] = "Data saved successfully";
    }
    else 
    {
      // display failed tempdata in view
      TempData["Message"] = "Sorry, an error has occurred";
    }
  //...etc
}
```

**View (place this anywhere you like in the view):**

```
@if (TempData["Message"] != null)
{
    @Html.Raw(TempData["Message"].ToString())
}
```

This example just uses a simple string, but you can use a more complex data structure if required (e.g. I imagine you might want to set colour schemes / CSS classes for success / failure, for instance, or add Javascript to get things like fade effects - you can place that script within your `if` statement. Maybe consider creating a re-usable partial view and a "Message" object to use as the model for it which can convey all that kind thing, and you can use it throughout your application.

N.B. If you're returning to the same view, you can always just use the ViewBag instead of TempData - TempData can be useful because will persist across requests, e.g. if you redirect to another action at the end of your current action, instead of directly returning a view.

Comment: Yes. I want to return to the same view. How can I determine in the `if` statement if the stored procedure is successful?

Comment: well generally if anything goes wrong with an entity framework operation you'd get an exception. So perhaps you need a try/catch block instead of if / else. But if that's what you're testing for, TBH it should be vanishingly rare that a simple insert query would fail entirely, unless maybe something goes wrong with the operating environment, e.g. network problem. So consider whether you really need to handle it...perhaps the application should be allowed to fail to a generic error page, and in the background you log the error for investigation and/or alert the support personnel.